# Are questions about mercurial working practises on topic for Programmers?

Tags: discussion, support, on-topic-definition

I want to ask a question regarding best practises for working with Mercurial within a small team.  This is more about strategy for managing repositories rather than commands for using Mercurial.

Is this a question better suited to Programmers or SO?

For reference, this is the question: [Recommended methodology for working with shared libraries and Mercurial](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/158847/recommended-methodology-for-working-with-shared-libraries-and-mercurial#comment303129_158847)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's about strategies, policies, procedures, or methodologies, I'd ask it here on Programmers. The practices on how to use Mercurial, or any version control system, falls under the broad category of configuration management, which is a practice of software engineering, which is explicitly listed as on-topic.

However, if it involves deployment of a Mercurial environment, tool support, or how to use Mercurial and any supporting tools such as IDE integration, I'd suggest Stack Overflow as the place to ask, since programming tool questions are on-topic there.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Thomas said make sure to keep the scope of the question fairly limited or there is good potential for it being closed as not constructive or not a real question, some topics involved with source control are borderline holy wars.

simply asking how best to use Mercurial for a small team, is not a good question.